# Is it safe to destroy an uninitialized FFTW plan?

Tags: c++, c, fftw

If one were to declare a plan as such, then immediately destroy it, is there a risk for segmentation fault?

```
fftw_plan myPlan;
fftw_destroy_plan(myPlan);
```

My gut feeling is maybe, but I do not know if fftw does any internal bookkeeping on these things to avoid freeing unallocated memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a risk. This appears to be the definition of `fftw_destroy_plan` in FFTW 3.3.3:

```
void X(destroy_plan)(X(plan) p)
{
     if (p) {
          X(plan_awake)(p->pln, SLEEPY);
          X(plan_destroy_internal)(p->pln);
          X(problem_destroy)(p->prb);
          X(ifree)(p);
     }
}
```

It uses the plan `p` as a pointer. So, if `p` is uninitialized, behavior not defined by the C standard results.

Even if we consider theoretical alternative implementations of FFTW rather than the actual code, there is a risk. Since the contents of `myPlan` are uncontrolled, they could happen to appear identical to a valid FFTW plan, in which case `fftw_destroy_plan` will attempt to destroy it. This almost certainly involves calling `free` on pointers in the plan, even if we consider theoretical alternative implementations of FFT rather than the actual code.

It is theoretically possible the FFTW API might be implemented with a fixed amount of space in the plan (with `fftw_plan` being a large `struct` rather than a pointer), so that dynamic memory allocation is not necessary, and `free` is not used. However, then there would be no need for a routine to destroy a plan. So the API design shows us it is designed with the expectation that dynamic memory allocation will be used.

Answer (score 3):

Well why take the chance? fftw_plan is an *opaque pointer type*. So you can write

```
fftw_plan myPlan = NULL;

// some code which may create a plan

if (myPlan)
    fftw_destroy_plan(myPlan);
```